# How to hide customised caption in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I am using a customised caption. It creates one title caption followed by another caption. I want to display the title caption in the list of figures, but not the second one. How could I hide the second caption in the list of figures?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%%%%%caption set up%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1}\newline\footnotesize#2}}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, tableposition=bottom, justification=justified}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[clip,width=1.0\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\mycaption{Caption for list of figures.}{Nor for list of figures.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually the caption command can be used as \caption[caption only for list of figures]{caption only under the image}, maybe you can adapt your newcommand accordingly, in such that you pass argument #1 into the square brackets?

Comment: `\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption[\textbf{#1}]{\textbf{#1}\newline\footnotesize#2}}`

Comment: A big thank you to both of you. I will follow @Simon Dispa 's solution.